Cannot convert dataframe column to a int64 data type
I have a problem.
In my Pandas DataFrame, I have a column called 'job' column. I've created a simple and custom transformer that will map values in that column that corresponds to the type of job. The problem arises when after mapping the values and inspecting it, the column now has a float data type.
[Here is the image, see the 'job' column]
(https://i.sstatic.net/yrImfOe0.png)
I figured this might affect the performance of my DecisionTreeClassifier and Support Vector Classifier model.
Here is the code snippet for the custom transformer that I've use
class PreprocessJobColumn (BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
def __init__ (self):
    self.dictionary_map = {
        "admin" : 1,
        "blue-collar" : 2,
        "entrepreneur" : 3,
        "housemaid" : 4,
        "management" : 5,
        "retired" : 6,
        "self-employed" : 7,
        "services" : 8,
        "student" : 9,
        "technician" : 10,
        "unemployed" : 11
    }

def map_job_values (self, element_to_process):
    if element_to_process in self.dictionary_map.keys():
        return self.dictionary_map.get(element_to_process, -1)

def fit_transform(self, X):
    # Create a copy of the dataset
    features_dataset_copy = X.copy()

    # Mapping values
    features_dataset_copy["job"] = features_dataset_copy["job"].apply(self.map_job_values)
    features_dataset_copy["job"] = features_dataset_copy["job"].astype("int64")
    return features_dataset_copy

If I run this code, it will give me this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IntCastingNaNError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a2bcaadbfea7> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 preprocess_education_column = PreprocessEducationColumn()
      3 
----> 4 df_copy = preprocess_job_column.fit_transform(df_copy)
      5 df_copy = preprocess_education_column.fit_transform(df_copy)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/astype.py in _astype_float_to_int_nansafe(values, dtype, copy)
    143     """
    144     if not np.isfinite(values).all():
--> 145         raise IntCastingNaNError(
    146             "Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer"
    147         )

IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

I tried removing null values to even creating conditions to remove rows that have a null value

read notice:[mre]

Please, take some time to read how to ask and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. A sample of readable input data should be added. Posting code/logs as images is not recommended and considered a bad practice.

Could it be because the "job" column contains values that are not in the dictionary you created? If that's the case you'll need to clean the data or edit the dictionary so that it contains all the values in your dataframe.

You can try
df['job'] = pd.to_numeric(df['job'], errors='coerce')

Pandas Doc's
